# Traducir "page" en datatables pagingType:input

Tags: datatables

Usando en datatables pagingType: input como se muestra en el ejemplo aparece una caja de busqueda con texto "Page" en ingles. ¿Sería posible traducir este texto?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example-table').dataTable({
        "pagingType": "input"   });  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Language](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html)

Puedes aplicar las traducciones con `language` de datatable.

> Cambiar la información de idioma mostrada por DataTables es tan simple como pasar un objeto de lenguaje al constructor DataTable.

Tambien vas a tener que cambiar a mano ciertos labels que el plugin escribe a manopla, como son page of

```
$(".paginate_page").text("Página");
$(".paginate_of").text($(".paginate_of").text().replace("of","de"));
```

En el siguiente ejemplo he colocado algunas de la página.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {            
        "paginationType": "input",
        "language": {
         "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
         "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
         "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
         "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
         "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
         "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
         "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
         "sInfoPostFix":    "",
         "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
         "sUrl":            "",
         "sInfoThousands":  ",",
         "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
         "oPaginate": {
          "sFirst":    "Primero",
          "sLast":     "Último",
          "sNext":     "Siguiente",
          "sPrevious": "Anterior"
         },
         "oAria": {
          "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
          "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
         }
        }                    
    } );
    $(".paginate_page").text("Página");
    $(".paginate_of").text($(".paginate_of").text().replace("of","de"));
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/pagination/input.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Silva</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gloria Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>Development Lead</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fiona Green</td>
            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shou Itou</td>
            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michelle House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Team Leader</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unity Butler</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$85,675</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$164,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
            <td>Secretary</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$645,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Olivia Liang</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$234,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$139,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thor Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$98,540</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$87,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: No entiendo como funciona esto. "lengthMenu" por ejemplo es una palabra reservada para cambiar un texto en concreto pero, ¿de donde busco la palabra reservada para "Page"?

Comment: @RicardoKra Podrías poner un pantallazo de donde esta? Es que no se a que palabra te refieres exactamente.

Comment: Es similar al que verás en este ejemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/bqpt85LL/
Fijate en el campo Page para la paginación. Eso es lo que pretendo traducir.
Gracias

Comment: Esas traducciones son las propias de Datatables:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/language
La de "Page...Of" que es la que you quiero traducir no aparece entre la lista del mencionado enlace. ¿Se puede añadir manualmente una traduccion para este "Page...Of"?
He visto que decias que añadias unas de "cosecha propia" pero por lo que yo veo todas aparecen en la lista de traducciones del enlace. ¿Alguna idea de como traducir esto?

Comment: @RicardoKra tienes razón. Algunos los vas a tener que cambiar a manopla ya que el plugin los escribe a mano tambien sobre el HTML. Te he modificado la respuesta, echale un ojo.

Comment: Bien por la primera traduccion (page por pagina) pero la segunda me esta fallando (la de "of"). ¿que podria estar mal? Gracias!

Comment: @RicardoKra La idea de la segunda es sacar el string, reemplazar of por de. y volver a meterlo. Yo lo he hecho en una sola linea, pero puedes guardarlo primero en una variable e ir pintado para ver que te va dando.

Comment: He usado esto: 

var txtOf = $(".paginate_of").text();
nTxtOf=txtOf.replace("of","de");
$(".paginate_of").text(nTxtOf);

pero parece que "replace" no funciona dentro de un datatable. Este mismo ejemplo lo he probado en local, sin datatable por medio, en un html sencillo y funciona, es decir reemplaza el texto de un span. Pero en el datatable no hace nada. No cambia nada.
¿Alguna idea de porque esta fallando? Gracias

Comment: Un dato mas, el "replace" parece que funciona dentro del datatable. He probado el mismo ejemplo con el ejemplo de "pagination_page" y ahí si cambia caracteres. Debe ser algo que hay mal pero no se que puede ser por que esto en local funciona y el mismo ejemplo en "pagination_page" funciona tambien. Los identificadores estan bien escritos asi que... no se que pueda ser. 
Si alguien sabe como resolverlo...gracias

Comment: @RicardoKra Igual se te escribe con otra clase, analiza el span a ver si puedes ver su clase y acceder a ella mediante consola. El snnipet que tienes de ejemplo tambien es un datatable y si hace cambio.

Comment: Si, se escribe con "paginate_of". Al acceder por consola a ese span dice:
<span class="paginate_of"> of 3766</span>
pero aqui no cambia nada. Sin embargo con tu ejemplo (y con el mio) si que cambia el "pagination_page" al cambiar alguna letra. Si me dices que en tu ejemplo si cambia no entiendo por que el mio no.

Comment: Tu ejemplo en local funciona perfectamente. Por alguna razon (que desconozco) en mi ejemplo no consigue pintar el "de". El span tiene la misma clase "paginate_of" por lo que es raro que no pueda hacer el replace correctamente (que por otra parte en tu ejemplo y en local consigue perfectamente). Al final lo que hice fue descargar el archivo .input.js y lo modifiqué para que aparezcan las dos palabras "Pagina" y "de". Un pequeño fallo en tu ejemplo es que funciona pero cuando cambias de pagina vuelve a aparecer el "of". 
Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @RicardoKra en eso tienes razon, deberia de controlarse la función de la paginacion. Pero lo que has comentado, si tienes la posibilidad de editar el código del plugin-input, mas que perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

También cuando construyas tu DT puedes usar un cdn

```
$('#example-table').dataTable({
        "pagingType": "input",
        'language': {
          url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
});
```